# Which graph with an automorphism group isomorphic to the quaternion group $Q_8$ minimizes $|V|+3|E|$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, latin-square

In [Symmetries of partial Latin squares](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ejc.2013.02.005), it is shown that for any graph $\Gamma=(V,E)$ with automorphism group $G$, there is a partial Latin square with $|V|+3|E|+49$ filled cells whose autotopism group is isomorphic to $G$.

Hence my question...

> Which graph with an automorphism group isomorphic to the quaternion group $Q_8$ minimizes $|V|+3|E|$?

The answer to the question [Smallest graph with automorphism group the quaternion $8$-group, $Q_8$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1316691/91818) gives an example of a 16-vertex 48-edge graph with automorphism group $Q_8$.  It could be one that minimizes $|V|+3|E|$.

I'm looking to find partial Latin rectangles that (a) have symmetry groups isomorphic to a given group $G$, and (b) have low weight [number of filled cells].  The quaternion group is among the groups of smallest order I have yet to compute examples.  The answer to this question will give an upper bound on the weight.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is incomplete in that it only gives the upper bound $|V| + 3 |E| \leq 138$, which improves significantly on the bound of 160 given by the graph in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1317629/155629) to the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1316691/91818).

That answer shows that any graph with automorphism group $Q_8$ has at least $16$ vertices. Now, [this presentation from a 2016 REU](http://khanalkripa.com/Presentation.pdf) by Edwards, Khanal, and Webster gives the minimum number $e(v)$ of edges among graphs on $v$ vertices with automorphism group $Q_8$ for the first several $v \geq 16$:
\begin{align*}
e(16) = e(17) &= 44 \\
e(18) = e(19) &= 40 \\
e(20)         &= 41 \\
\end{align*}
(This result doesn't appear to have been published otherwise.)

Among these the lowest value of $|V| + 3 |E|$ is achieved by a graph with $|V| = 18$, $|E| = 40$, for which $|V| + 3 |E| = 138$. Page 15 of the presentation gives an explicit example:
[image]
This leads to a partial Latin square with $138 + 49 = 187$ filled squares with autotopism group $Q_8$

In particular, if a graph with $v \geq 21$ vertices achieves a lower value of $|V| + 3 |E|$, it must have fewer than $\left\lceil 46 - \frac{v}{3}\right\rceil$ edges.